# Java polymorphism/abstract class help

Tags: java, polymorphism, abstract-class

I'm trying to set parameters for a abstract class:

```
public abstract class NewMath {
    public abstract int op (int intOne, int intTwo);
}
```

Here is the extended subclass:

```
public class MultMath extends NewMath {
    public int op (int intOne, int intTwo){
        return intOne + intTwo;
    }
}
```

But when I try to instantiate an object while defining the parameters like this:

```
public class TestNewMath {
    public static void main(String [] _args) {
        MultMath multObj = new MultMath(3,5);
    }
}
```

It doesn't work. It gives me this error:

```
TestNewMath.java:3: cannot find symbol
symbol  : constructor AddMath(int,int)
location: class AddMath
        AddMath addObj = new AddMath(3, 5);
```

I know I'm missing something. What is it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're calling a constructor with two int arguments, but you haven't created such a constructor. You have only created a method named 'op' that takes two int arguments.

Comment: Where do i put the constructor?

Comment: A constructor is a method without a return type and the name of the class. In this case 
  public MultMath(int intOne, int intTwo)

Answer (score 1):

You would put the constructor in the "MultMath" class, like so:

```
public MultMath(int arg0, int arg1){

}
```

This would get rid of your compile error.  Alternatively, you could do this:

```
public class TestNewMath {
  public static void main(String [] _args) {
    MultMath multObj = new MultMath();
     int x=1, y=2;
     multObj.op(x,y);        

}
```